# In Karate, what is the advantage of wrapping a Java function in a JavaScript function?

Tags: java, testing, interop, karate, java-interop

I can wrap a Java function like this:

```
* def myJavaMethod =
"""
function() {
     var Utils = Java.type('Utils');
     // use Number type in constructor
     var obj = new Utils(...);
     return obj.myJavaMethod();
}
"""
```

But why would I? I can use Java functions straight in the test scenarios, like this:

```
Scenario: Test exec and error value
* def Utils = Java.type('Utils');
* def ret = Utils.exec('echo "From Java" > /home/richard//karate-test/karate-0.9.6/out.txt');
* match read('out.txt') == "From Java\n";
* match Utils.exec('exit 123') == 123
```

Note: `exec` is a static method that uses a shell to execute the command given.

At least I tested this for **static** methods and that works fine without the JavaScript detour.
It seems that the JavaScript wrapper only adds an extra layer of complication.
Besides that, with the 'call' syntax I can only pass one parameter (that admittedly can be an entire object or array).
But, I can pass parameters straight to a Java function (using normal syntax) and even use the result in a match.
(I assume parameters and results are *implicitly* converted to a JavaScript value, that could be a JSON object or array).

So far, I miss to see the advantage of explicitly wrapping Java code inside JavaScript wrappers. I assume the problem is me, that is: I am missing some important point here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advantage is to reduce typing and when you have a lot of code re-use. For example, instead of:

```
* def foo = java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ''
```

You define it once:

```
* def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
```

And then call it wherever, and it is super-concise:

```
* def json = { foo: '#(uuid())' }
```

Comment: And indeed, your example is super compact assuming reuse

Comment: I may have found another case when have to use a JavaScript wrapper?
See for instance this:

* def request = <xml> ... </request>
\n
* def ret = Utils.tcp("server", 3840, 30000, 30000, #(request));
\n
* match ret == expected
\n
The substitution in the 'embedded expression' fails, since it  is not inside JSON.

Comment: @user2943111 you don't need embedded expressions when within round brackets. please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#enclosed-javascript